# Proper reading of 面

Tags: kanji, readings

I was looking for sample sentences for 面(おもて) when I saw these sentences in my dictionary.

> 決める前にこの問題を、あらゆる面(おもて)から考えてみよう。
> Let's consider the problem in all its bearings before making a decision.
>
> 倫理の面(おもて)で、たくさんの人々が遺伝子治療に反対している
> In ethical terms, a great many people are opposed to gene therapy.

I would not be surprised if it were read as めん, but is おもて a valid reading in this context?

Comment: What dictionary?

Comment: It's an app called Akebi.

Comment: Looks like that app is using the Tanaka Corpus. Please read http://www.manythings.org/corpus/warning.html

Comment: Furthermore, the Tanaka Corpus normally does not even contain furigana for its kanji, so it’s very likely that they are being machine-added. Which means you should not trust it at all.

Comment: That's a very good point. I have been noticing inconsistencies in kanji reading here and there, but brushed them off as isolated cases. Also, I didn't know that Tanaka corpus has that reputation. I do check Tangorin for other sample sentences. Is that reliable?

Comment: See the “Notice” and “Credits” section of https://tangorin.com/sentences combined with the last bullet of my last link.

Comment: Do you know of more reliable corpora that you can recommend? I use https://bonten.ninjal.ac.jp/ and http://nlt.tsukuba.lagoinst.info/search/ if I want to be more thorough but now I am not so sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%9D%A2_%28%E3%81%8A%E3%82%82%E3%81%A6%29/),
面{おもて} is explained in the header as

《「おも（面）」に、方向・方面を表す「て」の付いたもの。**正面のほう**、の意》

before the items in the section. So, the basic meaning is in the front of something if you pronounce it as 面{おもて} .

I think the word : 面 has to be pronounced as 面{めん} in your sentences because it is close to "facet/aspect" in meaning. You might want to see something in any angles and not limited to the front of something.